# How to open a form in editable mode-Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

views.py is

```
def when(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        reportform = ReportForm(data=request.POST)

        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')
    else:
        reportform = ReportForm()
    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{
                  'newreport_menu': True, 
                  'form': reportform,
                   },
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I can insert and save the data in database.So after saving the data,if i again open this page the entered data should be in editable mode.i.e the last entered data should be displayed in the field.How to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`instance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) parameter in the form instantiation call.

Answer (score 0):

```
def when(request, instance_id=None):

    report = None
    if instance_id:
        report = Report.objects.get(pk=instance_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        reportform = ReportForm(data=request.POST, instance=report)

        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')
    else:
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)
    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{
              'newreport_menu': True, 
              'form': reportform,
               },
               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Keep two urls, one for creating and another for editing, but both of them will use this same view.

```
url(r'^create/$', 'app.views.when', name='create_report'),
url(r'^edit/(?P<instance_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.when', name='edit_report')
```

Comment: No, this won't update the existing instance on save. You need to pass `instance` in the instantation on POST as well.

Comment: It can seem like the same page if you use same context but you need two urls, else how will you know which Report you want to edit. You need some way to send the instance_id of the report you want to edit.

Comment: If you want to keep same url, option is to send the instance_id in GET data.

Comment: If i am using two urls,one for adding and other for editable mode,is it possible to achieve in same template.

Comment: Yeah, it is. View and template would be same. Just two different urls. Both urls pointing to same view. Since template is decided by the view, so if you use the same view you will be using same template as well.